# How to set original value after foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a foreach loop and I want to set the original value so I can return it as a List.

```
 List<SurveyModel> surveys = new List<SurveyModel>();

 //code that adds a bunch of survey items to surveys

foreach(var survey in surveys)
            {
                var questionResponses = await GetSurveyDraftQuestionsAsync(survey.Id);
                foreach (var questionResponse in questionResponses)
                {
                    questions.Add(new SurveyQuestionResponseModel()
                    {
                        Id = questionResponse.Id,
                        SortOrder = questionResponse.SortOrder,
                        Name = questionResponse.Name,
                        IsPreSelect = questionResponse.IsPreSelect,
                        IsBrandLoop = questionResponse.IsBrandLoop,
                        AnswerType = questionResponse.AnswerType,
                        SurveyTeamflags = questionResponse.SurveyTeamflags,
                        CategoryId = questionResponse.CategoryId,
                        Notes = questionResponse.Notes,
                        CategoryName = questionResponse.CategoryName
                    });
                }
                survey.Questions = questions;
}
```

now I want to set the original surveys with the value of survey

Comment: Please read [ask] This question is vague and a little unclear

Comment: this code work correctly . survey.Questions = questions; do set survey original. where is problem?